# React fetching a remote API, the response is not what I expected

Tags: reactjs, fetch

In my `LatestBookSlide.js`, I wrote the following code:

```
class LatestBookSlide extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://api/book/hello')
      .then(function (response){
        console.log(response);
      });
  }

}
```

The fetching is now OK thanks to CORS added (discussed in this thread: [Silex "->after" middleware usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42837703/silex-after-middleware-usage)).

The console log shows the response like this:

```
07:01:34.672 Response { type: "cors", url: "http://api/book/hello", 
redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, statusText: "OK", headers: Headers, 
bodyUsed: false } 1 bundle.js:36481:10
```

But this is not what I expected. A direct call to that API in browser will return below:

```
{"status":200,"out":{"res":"Welcome to RSYWX API interface."}}
```

Are there some further steps I am missing here?

Answer (score 4):

React has nothing to do with it;

`fetch` call returns a promise with a `Response` object. That's what you're seeing.

Response object has information about the status of the response as well as some convenience methods like `.json()`, `.text()`, `.formData()`, etc.

If you're expecting the server's response to be json, you should do this:

```js
fetch('http://api/book/hello')
  .then(function (response) {
    return response.json()
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response); // now this is the body of the response
  })
```

You might also want to check whether the response was not an error by checking the `status` field of the `Response` object.

Read more about fetch [here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch) and [here](https://davidwalsh.name/fetch)

Answer (score 1):

What implementation of `fetch()` are you using? Try calling the `json()` method on the response:

```
  response.json().then(function(data) {  
    console.log(data);  
  });
```